# move_uploaded_file salva no banco de dados, mas não salva imagem na pasta! Alguem ajuda

Tags: php

```
<h1>Upload de Arquivos</h1>

<form name="enviarImagem" action="enviar.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Arquivo<br> <input type="file" name="img" value=""><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Enviar" name ="enviar">





<?php



$name = $_FILES["img"]["name"];
$temp = $FILES["img"]["tmp_name"];

/*var_dump($name);
var_dump($temp);*/

$banco = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "projeto");

$sql = "INSERT INTO imagem (nome) VALUES ('{$name}')";

$banco->query($sql);
$banco->close();


move_uploaded_file($temp, "./imagens/".$name);

header("Location: upload.php");

?>
```

Comment: Verifique se a pasta tem permissão. Verifique também se o caminho está correto dando o comando realpath("./imagens/".$name); e veja se está correto.

Comment: num dos `$_FILES` falta um `_`

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde,

Tenta com o seguinte código:

```
$link = "nomepasta/".$_FILES["img"]["name"];

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'], $link);
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá, tente assim:

## Upload de Arquivos

Arquivo

```
<?php

$name = $_FILES["img"]["name"];
$temp = $_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"];

/*var_dump($name);
var_dump($temp);*/

$banco = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "projeto");

$sql = "INSERT INTO imagem (nome) VALUES ('{$name}')";

$banco->query($sql);
$banco->close();

$dir = "./imagens";

@mkdir($dir);


move_uploaded_file($temp, ".$dir."/".$name);

header("Location: upload.php");

?>
```

O seu erro deve ser por conta de não estar informando o caminho correto para a imagem... Experimente colocar `@mkdir` para criar a pasta e ver onde ela foi criada... Assim poderá ajustar até criar a pasta no local correto!